# Data structures and interfaces, for an extendable "Tournament Bracketing" system

Tags: c#, interface, tournament

**Background**

I am in the early stages of writing a "tournament bracketing" application (C#, although any object-oriented language would be appropriate).  This application would theoretically generate bracket sheets for multiple types of tournaments:

- Single-elimination
- Double-elimination
- Double-elimination with "true second"
- Round robin
- Swiss-system
- ...and probably more that I've never even heard of, before.

For each type of tournament, I'd like to implement the 'bracket algorithm' as an instance of a common interface.  In this way, I can make the system extensible, and easily add support for additional brackets in the future.

Given a variable list of 'competitors' - the user could simply choose their desired bracket plugin and *poof*, there's the generated bracket!

**Design Challenges**

I am currently struggling to visualize a design for bracketing; the needed APIs of the interface, and - more importantly - I'm not sure how to *generically* and *flexibly* represent the bracket 'model,' as a data structure.  Some sort of node map, I guess?

Ideally, I'd need the interface to:

- Accept a variable-sized list of competitors as input
- Generate a graph (or other) structure as output, representing the 'flow' of the bracket.
- The graph structure would need to support some sort of 'Win / Lose' API, to 'advance' the various competitors through the bracket, and fill it in as it goes.

**The Question**

I wish I had a better way to phrase this question;

- *How I do 'dis?*
- What are your thoughts?
- What interface structure makes the most sense?
- How do I model this generically, in code?

**My Initial Flailings**

It wouldn't be a StackOverflow question unless I put some code on paper.  Here are my initial thoughts;

```
// A plugin interface; generates a tournament bracket, given a list of competitors
public interface IBracketSheetGenerator
{
    public IBracketSheet CreateBracket(IEnumerable<Competitor> competitors);
}

// Parent data structure, used to model a tournament bracket
public interface IBracketSheet
{
    public IEnumerable<Competitor> Competitors { get; }
    public IEnumerable<IBracketNode> Matches { get; }
}

// Node representing a single competitor match
public interface IBracketNode
{
    public Competitor Left { get; }
    public Competitor Right { get; }

    public IBracketNode Winner { get; }
    public IBracketNode Loser { get; }

    // Advance the winner to the next winner's match,
    // and the loser to the loser's match.
    public Advance(Competitor winner, Competitor loser);
}
```

Right off the bat, I can see some shortcomings with my first attempt;

- How do I represent the 'winner' of the entire bracket?
- How do I represent losers who have been 'eliminated' from the bracket?
- How do I signal that the bracket has been completed/resolved?  What does a resolved bracket look like?
- Does this framework support 'strange' brackets which don't fall into the simple 'elimination' mold (like round robin, for instance)?

Answer (score 1):

Just brainstorming here, but I guess I would model the concept of a `Round` too. For the elimination systems rounds already make sense, but you should be able to simulate rounds for the other systems as well. I think the total number of rounds can be predetermined for all of them.

Each round has matches and each match has winners and losers, the implementation of the bracket system would be able to generate the next matches after a round is completed and you supply the outcome of each match.

If a competitor is not placed on a match in the subsequent round, they're "out". Perhaps the bracket system could return an ordered list of competitors representing the current standing, or even a custom `CompetitorAndScore` class that contains statistics?

Comment: An interesting approach.  Off-hand, I'm not sure what the additional "Round" structure brings to the table, though my gut agrees it must provide some sort of organizational value.  Assigning an arbitrary 'score' is also an intuitive way to determine standings at the end of the bracket.  It seems that the brackets themselves would be responsible for determining what 'score value' to assign a winner vs a loser in elimination-style tournaments.  You certainly have my upvote, though I wouldn't quite mark it as a complete 'answer' in its current form.